# Execute function from another script in a script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, timeout

I have two scripts running in the body of my page. When "a" is pressed on the keyboard, another script runs. How can I add some delay and then trigger the first script again? I have tried with the code below, it does not work. Prefferably, I would like to cancel the first timeout in the beginning of the second script as well.

```
 <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
  function reloading(){
      $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                    
      data: "",                      
      dataType: 'json',             
      success: function(data)        
      {
        var id = data[0];             
          _id = id;
        var vname = data[1];           
        var message = data[2]; 
        var timestamp = data[3]; 
        var field1 = data[4]; 
        _field1 = field1;
        var val2 = parseInt(field1, 10) ;
        _val2 = val2;
        $('#output').hide().html( message ).fadeIn("slow");   
         $('#username').hide().html( vname +":" ).fadeIn("slow");
      setTimeout(function(){
      reloading();
    }, 60000);

      }
      });
  }
  reloading();
}); 
  </script>

  <script>
  $(document).jkey('a',function() {
     $.post("update.php", { "id": _id} )
      $('#output').hide().html( "<i>Message</i><br> <br>" +_val2 +" additional." ).fadeIn("slow");
      $('#username').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#valg1').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#valg2').fadeOut("fast");
      });
     setTimeout("reloading()",1000); 
</script>
```

Comment: Your function is not visible outside the anonymous page load. Move it outside the anonymous function or create a scope of your own

Comment: Also your "a" code did not contain the call - it was outside the function

Comment: Ah, big mistake. Shouldn't it be possible to run the entire first function if I give it a name and call it using setTimeout?

`$(function content(){
  function reloading(){
      $.ajax({        `   and then   `setTimeout("content()",3000);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put reloaded() in global scope to access it from another script. Right now it is inside an anonymous function (a bit of a hack to mitigate global scope pollution), but for your case if it isn't feasible to merge the two scripts into one, you are going to have to pollute global scope.

If it is a one-off function, give it a unique prefix or something:

```
myApp_reloaded();
```

If you have a bunch of functions that need to be in the global scope, create a wrapper object. There are a bunch of different patterns you can use, I prefer this...

```
    function MyApp() {

    }
    MyApp.prototype.reloaded = function () {
     // reload func body here
    }




var myApp = new MyApp();
```

now you can access the methods globally:

```
myApp.reloaded();
```

Comment: Why haven't I thought about combining the two scripts? It turns out that it's possible. Could you help me with the positioning and correct calling of the script?

Comment: Yeah but I have faith that you can figure it out yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack until someone comes with a more elegant one that does not pollute the global scope

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var tId;
function reloading(){
  $.ajax({                                      
    url: 'api.php',                    
    data: "",                      
    dataType: 'json',             
    success: function(data) {
      var id = data[0];             
      _id = id;
      var vname = data[1];           
      var message = data[2]; 
      var timestamp = data[3]; 
      var field1 = data[4]; 
      _field1 = field1;
      var val2 = parseInt(field1, 10) ;
      _val2 = val2;
      $('#output').hide().html( message ).fadeIn("slow");   
      $('#username').hide().html( vname +":" ).fadeIn("slow");
      clearTimeout(tId);
      tId=setTimeout(function(){ reloading();}, 60000);
    }
  });
}

$(function (){
  reloading();
}); 

$(document).jkey('a',function() {
  $.post("update.php", { "id": _id} )
  $('#output').hide().html( "<i>Message</i><br> <br>" +_val2 +" additional." ).fadeIn("slow");
  $('#username').fadeOut("fast");
  $('#valg1').fadeOut("fast");
  $('#valg2').fadeOut("fast");
  clearTimeout(tId);
  tId = setTimeout(function() { reloading()},1000); 

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'll rather try to understand and sort out the global scope. I'll give you an update on wether it works or not.

Comment: Well seems I was correct on that account, but because I expressed my doubts you chose the other answer?